# How to update Google.Play.Services.Maps to 32.961 or higher?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

https://github.com/alexsorokoletov/Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils

I am trying to use that nuget for my xamarin forms android map. However it depends on Google.Play.Services.Maps to be version 32.961 or higher but my current version is 29.0 and when I try to update it I need to update lots of packages (Support.Design, Support.v4 etc) and visual studio is not letting me update that either. I believe it's something about the MonoAndroid version. I get this error message `You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.`

Any ideas how I can successfully install this nuget?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Forms changed the way it depends on the Android support libraries a few versions ago.

You can see in the NuGet package (I have 2.3.4.247 installed) that MonoAndroid v1.0 requires Android support libraries to be equal to 23.3.0, but MonoAndroid v7.0 requires the version to be greater than or equal to 23.3.0.

To update the Android support libraries you need to ensure you have the latest Android SDK installed in the Android SDK manager, then change the Compile using Android Version (Target Framework) on the Application tab of the project options to be Use Latest Platform, and the Target Android Version on the Android Manifest tab to be Use Compile using SDK version.

Once you have done this you should be able to update the support libraries. I did that by selecting Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and updating in NuGet.